# Are the different timings of day dominated by particular guna?

Tags: time, gunas

Are the different timings of day dominated by a particular guna be it sattva, rajasic or tamasic?

If yes, what is prominent at which time?

Comment: 4-6 Sattva, day time work rajas and for sleep tamas